How to set multiple triggers for one job in Quartz.NET
I am having a trouble with setting multiple triggers for one job.
Here is the example.
StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

await scheduler.Start();

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SampleJob>()
    .WithIdentity("sampleJob", "group1")
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger2", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();

await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger1);
await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger2);

await _scheduler.Shutdown();

public class SampleJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Executed {DateTime.Now}");
            
    }
}

This code stops at the second job scheduling process with the exception "Quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: 'Unable to store Job: 'group1.sampleJob', because one already exists with this identification.'
"
How could I set multiple triggers for one job?
Thanks.
I have set different name for each trigger, but they are considered as the same trigger.
I would like to know how I can distinguish those two triggers.
Or is there a way to set triggers at once?

for scheduling multiple triggers for a single job
we can use overload method await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, new List<ITrigger>() { trigger1,trigger2},true);
